# How to create a bash script using a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to create a post-installer script which itself creates a bash script (startapp script). 
This is the original startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `wmctrl -l | grep -c "$2"` != 0 ]
then wmctrl -a "$2"
else $1 &
fi
```

And this is my post-installer script

```
#!/bin/sh
# CONFIGURE Teamviewer startup link
sudo echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nif [ `wmctrl -l | grep -c "$2"` != 0 ]\nthen wmctrl -a "$2"\nelse $1 &\nfi" > /usr/local/bin/startapp
# Activate script
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startapp
```

But when I checked the script with `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/startapp`, I get this weirdly modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ 6 != 0 ]
then wmctrl -a 
else  &
fi
```

Could you tell me why the system modified it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *here document*

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<'EOF' | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/startapp
#!/bin/bash
if [ `wmctrl -l | grep -c "$2"` != 0 ]
then wmctrl -a "$2"
else $1 &
fi
EOF
```

Use of quotes (of any kind - including a backslash `\EOF`) in the delimiter prevents the *invoking* shell from expanding substitutions prematurely.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This worked beautifully! Toast to steeldriver! I see, so you are piping the stdinput into a file. This opens so many more options for me to customize my post-install script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backticks, because these are intrepolated inside your quoted string and therefore executed.